# Linear operator with dense range but not full range

Tags: functional-analysis

Can you give an example of a Banach space $E$ and a linear operator $A \in \mathcal L(E)$ such that $A$ has dense range but not full range, i.e.  $ran(A) \neq E = \overline{ran}(A)$?

Clearly, $E$ has to be infinite dimensional because otherwise the range of a linear operator is always closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, $E = \ell^p$ with $1 \le p < \infty$, $(A x)_i = x_i/i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the space of continuous functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$, with the sup norm. Now define $A(f)(x) = \int_{0}^x f(t) \, dt$.

Comment: I think we need to use a variant of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to show range is dense!

Answer (score 0):

You can take any normal, compact and injective operator on a Hilbert space. E.g. $E = \ell^2$ and consider the multiplication operator $$(A \, x)_n = x_n \, t_n,$$ where $\{t_n\}$ is a non-zero null sequence.

Comment: Why do we need injective?

Comment: If a bounded, normal operator is injective, its range is dense (and for a compact operator, the range could not be the whole space).